# Cleaning all columns of Data Frame at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to write a line or two of code to
look at *every* column from a data frame for any blanks
or non-numeric values, such as `N/A` or `NaN`, and replace them with `0`.

Here are some attempts:

Given a data frame=df, with total columns *n* I tried:

```
df[,c(1:n)]<-sub("NaN","0",df[,c(1:n)])
```

And this was an attempt to filter the entire data frame:

```
df[df[,c(1:n)]=='NaN',"c(1:n)"]
```

My goal is to do this *without* using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df[is.na(df)] <- 0` and `df[df == NaN] <- 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is.finite()`:

```
 df[!is.finite(df)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the data.table package, you can do this with .SDcols. Having the data would be cleaner, but with some random data we can replicate.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = rep(c(1,NA),20),
           b = rep(c(NA,2),20))

DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))]
```